# CMake 3.4.0 Including multiple files

Tags: cmake

I was using CMake 2.8.10.1 before and while configuring with that was alright. Now when I switched to CMake 3.4.0 the same CMakelists.txt giving following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:31 (INCLUDE):
  include called with wrong number of arguments.  include() only takes one
  file.
```

I used old CMake again and it is working fine with the same file. Following is the part of CMakelists

```
FIND_PACKAGE ( ITK)
IF ( ITK_FOUND)
INCLUDE( ${USE_ITK_FILE} )  //Line 31
ENDIF( ITK_FOUND)
```

Do I need to change some syntax here?

Comment: Can you print out the value of USE_ITK_FILE? I assume there are multiple entries or maybe aspace in the name. Try to sourround the variable with quotation marks. If you want to include kultiple files with a list, you have to iterate over the list and call includefor every entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason was USE_ITK_FILE is now obsolete and it was working with 2.8.10.1 due to backward compatibility. As Given [here](http://www.na-mic.org/svn/Slicer3-lib-mirrors/trunk/CMake/Modules/FindITK.cmake)

```
#  USE_ITK_FILE - The full path to the UseITK.cmake file.  
#                 This is provided for backward 
#                 compatability.  Use ITK_USE_FILE
#                 instead.
```

I changed it to ITK_USE_FILE and it worked.